# Where can I find color themes for Visual Assist X?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-assist-x

It's relatively easy to find color themes for Visual Studio. A quick search turns up tens or hundreds of themes without much effort, such as a Vibrant Ink clone, and some of Jeff Atwood's original themes.

I use Visual Assist X -- pretty much the best Visual Studio plugin I've ever used, but it changes the color of code on the screen. So if you choose a different theme, the parts of the code that VAX is changing still show up in their original colors.

I'm particularly interested in darker themes, because sometimes I prefer a light on dark color scheme for getting things done.

Is there an easy way to find such things or am I stuck tweaking?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the documentation correctly, you just have to adapt syntax highlighting of VAX on your own. Keep in mind that some of VAX's colours are defined at Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors.

For more info look here: http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/color.asp

In particular: http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/color.asp#darkBackground

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about actual themes, but if you click the 'use defaults' button in the VA X options dialogue while your editor has a dark background, it will switch the colours to more appropriate ones.